# Undermenu needs to float

Tags: css

Check out http://clients.newblack.ro/gtools/ . I need to make the undermenu(the one containing the cart icon in the right side and the "Bine ati venit..." in the left side, just under the menu) float if the user scrolls down the page. I want it to stick to the upper side of the page. I know there are ways to do this with JS but I'd prefer a CSS only solution. I tried with position: fixed; and it doesn't stay where I want it to. Please inspect element and provide an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I might be wrong but what you want to do is that, when the user as scrolled PAST the menu, it will become fixed to the top of the page, right? I think that can only be done with JS. Also read the FAQs on how to make a question, I'm not sure yours complies to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in jQuery. You can get the position in px from the top with $(window).scrollTop(), then if someone has scrolled down more than 200px, add css to the nav bar to give it a fixed position, so it sticks to the top of the browser widow.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var posFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(posFromTop > 200){
        // if more than 200px from the top add fixed position css to element
        } else {
        // otherwise reset the css.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried using    position: fixed;
   top: 0; but it won't work either because it sticks to the upper part of the page but it doesn't dislay as it should when it's not scrolled down, i'd really like a css only solution, i'm doing it for a friend and he wants it this way... yes Elaine, that's what I want, sorry for the format of the question

Comment: Using position:fixed; top:0; left:0 will position it in the top left of the browser window,. You can offset this with margin - top/left. But that's the only way you're going to get it to work, because you can only detect the scroll position with Javascript, there isn't a CSS only solution.

**Edit**
You might need to remove the z-index on #top-bar

Comment: thanks for the answers, that clarified everything :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called "sticky menu". See if this helps: http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/11/sticky-menus-are-quicker-to-navigate/

This example may be what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/widgetpc/MRv37/

```
posicionarMenu();

$(window).scroll(function() {    
    posicionarMenu();
});

function posicionarMenu() {
    var altura_del_header = $('header').outerHeight(true);
    var altura_del_menu = $('nav').outerHeight(true);

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= altura_del_header){
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        $('.content').css('margin-top', (altura_del_menu) + 'px');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.content').css('margin-top', '0');
    }
}
```

(this is not my solution, I took it from this web: http://www.widget-101.com/web/tips-web/como-hacer-un-menu-pegajoso-con-css-y-jquery-sticky-menu/)

Comment: Sticky menu won't work because my menu is not on top of the page in initial position

Comment: that's why you need JS! else the fixed solution would work for you. I'll edit my answer.